# Do not want to print multiple statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I don't want my code to print other statements when the statement "is not a letter of the alphabet" is printed. Please help! I am still a noobie.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int int_ch;

    do {

        printf("Type in an alphabet letter:");
        scanf("%c%*c", &ch);

        int_ch = (int)ch;
        printf("Ch has ascii value %d\n", ch);

        if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
        {
            int_ch = int_ch - 32;
        }
        else if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            int_ch = int_ch + 32;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Is not a letter of the Alphabet.");
        }

        //THIS HERE

        ch = (char)int_ch;

        printf("Ch is now %c\n", ch);
        printf("Ch is now ascii value %d\n", int_ch);

    } while (ch != '#');

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You could use the "continue" keyword

Comment: Insert the keyword `continue` into the `else` branch after `printf ("Is not a letter of the Alphabet.");` only if ch != '#'

Answer (score 0):

add `continue` is this `else-statement`

```
            else
            {
                printf("Is not a letter of the Alphabet.");
                continue;
            }
```

The `continue` statement skips the current iteration of the loop and continues with the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the statement `continue;` after the `printf()` statement:

```
printf("Is not a letter of the Alphabet.");
continue;
```

which will let the program flow pass directly to the condition of the `do while`-loop:

---

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int int_ch;

    do {

        printf("Type in an alphabet letter: ");
        scanf("%c%*c", &ch);

        int_ch = (int)ch;
        printf("Ch has ascii value %d\n", ch);

        if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z'))
        {
            int_ch = int_ch - 32;
        }
        else if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z'))
        {
            int_ch = int_ch + 32;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Is not a letter of the Alphabet.\n\n");
            continue;
        }

        ch = (char)int_ch;

        printf("Ch is now %c\n", ch);
        printf("Ch is now ascii value %d\n", int_ch);

    } while (ch != '#');

    return (0);
}
```

Execution:

```
Type in an alphabet letter: 7    
Ch has ascii value 55        
Is not a letter of the Alphabet.                   

Type in an alphabet letter: (Waiting for data for another iteration)
```